# spring-jpa PersistentObjectException

Tags: jpa

Не получается получить доступ к данным используя Spring-JPA

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "spitter")
public class Spitter {
    private static long schet = 0;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "iduser")
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String fullName;

    public Spitter() {
    }

    public Spitter(String username, String password, String fullName) {
        this.id=schet++;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Spitter{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", fullName='" + fullName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Spring_JPA.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

       <context:annotation-config />

       <context:component-scan
               base-package="dao" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <list>
                <value>model</value>
                <value>dao</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform"
                  value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    </bean>

       <bean id="dataSource"
             class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName"
                        value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
              <property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/DataBase/HSQL/SIA_HSQLDB.tmp/sia_db" />
              <property name="username" value="sa" />
              <property name="password" value="" />
       </bean>

       <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>


    <bean id="txManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>dao</value>
                <value>model</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="spitter">
        <class>model.Spitter</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver"
                      value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/DataBase/HSQL/SIA_HSQLDB.tmp/sia_db" />
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.user"
                      value="sa" />
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.password"
                      value="" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

dao

```
package dao;

import model.Spitter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Repository("jparep")
@Transactional
public class JPARepositoryImpl implements Rep {
    private static final String RECENT_SPITTLES =
            "SELECT s FROM Spittle s";
    private static final String ALL_SPITTERS =
            "SELECT s FROM Spitter s";
    private static final String SPITTER_FOR_USERNAME =
    "SELECT s FROM Spitter s WHERE s.username = :username";
    private static final String SPITTLES_BY_USERNAME =
            "SELECT s FROM Spittle s WHERE s.spitter.username = :username";
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em; // Для внедрения EntityManager
@Transactional
    public void addSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
        em.persist(spitter); // Использование EntityManager
    }

    @Transactional
    public Spitter getSpitterById(long id) {
        return em.find(Spitter.class, id); // Использование EntityManager
    }
    @Transactional
    public void saveSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
        em.merge(spitter); // Использование EntityManager
    }
}
```

dbshema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SPITTER;

--USER TABLE
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SPITTER (
IDUSER INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
USERNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
FULLNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

test_data.sql

```
INSERT INTO SPITTER  (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FULLNAME) VALUES ('Roma','1','Luch');
INSERT INTO SPITTER (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FULLNAME) VALUES ('Kate','2','Luch');
INSERT INTO SPITTER (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FULLNAME) VALUES ('Yaro','3','Luch');
INSERT INTO SPITTER (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FULLNAME) VALUES ('Alin','4','Luch');
INSERT INTO SPITTER (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FULLNAME) VALUES ('Alex','5','Luch');
```

Тестирую так:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring_JPA.xml");
        Rep test = (Rep)context.getBean("jparep");
        test.addSpitter(new Spitter("yaspring","on","ay"));
```

Вылетаю так:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: model.Spitter
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.persist(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.persist(Unknown Source)
    at dao.JPARepositoryImpl.addSpitter(JPARepositoryImpl.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.addSpitter(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: model.Spitter
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Рекомендуется делать более компактные примеры...

Comment: Не знаю просто в чем может быть проблема - вот и пришлось все класы кинуть

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался -В конструкторе Spitter закоментил

```
public Spitter(String username, String password, String fullName) {
        /*this.id=schet++;*/
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
```

но метод эд все равно не работал пока не переписал SpringJPA.xml на org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

       <context:annotation-config />

       <context:component-scan
               base-package="dao" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <list>
                <value>model</value>
                <value>dao</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform"
                  value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    </bean>

       <bean id="dataSource"
             class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName"
                        value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
              <property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/DataBase/HSQL/SIA_HSQLDB.tmp/sia_db" />
              <property name="username" value="sa" />
              <property name="password" value="" />
       </bean>

       <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>


    <bean id="txManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory">
            <ref local="entityManagerFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="dbschema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="test_data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <!--В книге Spring in action было так, но у меня не работал в таком варианте метод add-->
<!--
    <bean id="txManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>dao</value>
                <value>model</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
          </bean>-->



    <!--    <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>dao</value>
                    <value>model</value>
                </list>
            </property>

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>-->


</beans>
```